# Need help setting up an environment variable

Tags: environment-variables

I want to create an environment variable that does this:

```
java -jar HepRApp.jar
```

However, this command only works when I am in `/`. How can I create an environment variable the changes my directory to `/` and then runs the jar file?

Comment: Variables don't do things. They carry values. Possibly you want to create an alias for the command `java -jar /HepRApp.jar`.

Comment: I want to create something where if i type $hep it will change my directory to / and then do "java -jar HepRApp.jar"

Answer (score 1):

You are doing wrong. What you need is either to make a script (which does what you want) and make it accessible by the OS or define an Alias which represents one command.

#### Making script:

To make your script accessible to the OS you have two options:

- put your script in a directory which is known for the OS. the list of these directories is saved in `$PATH` variable and can be get by running `echo $PATH`, something like this: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`
- introduce the directory in which you have the script to the OS by adding it to `$PATH` variable. Lets say the directory is in `/home/username/myscripts`. You can add this path to the `$PATH` by running: `export PATH=$PATH:/home/username/myscripts`

#### Making Alias

Based on [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command)):

> In computing, alias is a command in various command line interpreters
>   (shells) such as Unix shells, 4DOS/4NT and Windows PowerShell, which
>   enables a replacement of a word by another string. It is mainly used
>   for abbreviating a system command, or for adding default arguments to
>   a regularly used command.

So, now you can do this:

Edit your `.bashrc` and find the section related to Alias (you can put it anywhere but for the sake of discipline and readability, it is better to keep relevant items together) and introduce the new alias as following:

```
alias hep='cd /; java -jar HepRApp.jar'
```

now onward, if you use `ccc` it will run the command you have defined for it.

Comment: Hello. So What I want to do is put this in my .bashrc file. Right now I have:  export hep="java -jar HepRApp.jar":cd /                                                                            However, it does not seem to be working. What I want to do is when I start terminal, I type $hep then it will change the directory to / and then run the java command

Comment: I think what you are talking about is not variable, is alias. Alias is what you assign to one specific command. For example in my `.bashrc` there is line saying `alias ll='ls -alF'` this means if I run `ll` in bash, it will automatically run `ls -alF`. So, you should define alias (not variable). See the update in my answer

Comment: Aliases are deprecated. Use a function instead:  `hep()( cd /; java -jar HepRApp.jar )` (Note that this runs in a subshell. Replace parens with braces to run in the current shell.)